# how to increase the code size limit in trigger block appbuilder

Tags: progress-4gl

how to increase the code size limit in trigger block appbuilder 
i not able to write a code in trigger block in appbuilder(adm2),how to increase the size of the trigger block.in app builder.

Question :
i want to increase the size of trigger block ,i want to write more no.of lines in the trigger block.which option i will use in app builder..

thank you sir.

FOR EACH db1.vehicles WHERE vehicles.ad-num MATCHES keywordi OR string(vehicles.sl-num) MATCHES keywordi
            OR vehicles.product-id MATCHES keywordi OR vehicles.product-name no-lock:
end.

Comment: What version of progress?  Is there an error message?

Comment: What does the "FOR EACH" have to do with anything?  To the extent that you are really coding like that -- "matches" is a terrible function to use in a WHERE clause, it will result in a table scan because it cannot be bracketed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to increase the -inp and/or -tok client startup parameters.

Or perhaps a different startup parameter depending on what error message you are actually seeing.

But if you are writing code that runs into these limits you would be better served to stop and reconsider the code you are writing.  You are probably not organizing it in a very effective manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the trigger code and turn it into an include, then instantiate that inside the trigger code to use the section editor again. But you should review your code, chances are you don't need all that code to be in a single trigger code.